# disapearing mesh

Tags: modeling, texturing, physics, cloth-simulation

Why is my mesh disapearing when I add cloth physics?
[image: before add cloths]

[image: after add cloths]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I am modeling a flag and now I want to add cloth to the flag in the physics properties, but my plane object disappears When I add this mode

Comment: Have you pinned the flag to the flagpole? See [this](https://youtu.be/fX_87v7SA9k) tutorial.

Comment: Never seen this tutorial before....thanks a lot

Comment: How can I completely reset everything in blender.... all my tabs and types is Messed up like uv Editing...cloth physics & ... and I can't fix all of this and my modeling is in trouble
What should I do???
Help me pleasee

Comment: Please ask that in a different question including images of your Blender window and if possible your Blend file which you can share via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions there.

Comment: I can't ask a diffrent question about this because of quality standards‍♀️

Comment: Please share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/